# Windows Phone 8 read Smart card

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to use pinvoke.net with Windows Phone 8?

Something like `[DllImport(" winscard.dll ")]`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use DLLImport in WP8.

I've answered a similar question about reading Credit Cards on WP8 that applies to Smart Cards as well. See @ [Windows 8 Phone - access to NFC reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314228/windows-8-phone-access-to-nfc-reader/13334723#13334723)