# windows 8 mobile native api allows to capture the credit card data?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I need to know is there any native API to store the credit card information in  Windows 8 Mobile. I found a lot about NFC technology. Our requirement is storing the credit card information in wallet only by touch the credit card with phone like storing business card info by tapping using NFC.

[Windows 8 Phone - access to NFC reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314228/windows-8-phone-access-to-nfc-reader)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Wallet-payment-instruments-85c2a7a0

I could see some answers in this post. But it doesn't exactly matches our requirement.In the second link there says that tapping a credit card is it possible to tap an store the info of credit card in the wallet app.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API in the public SDK that will allow you to store credit card information outside of the wallet.

You haven't said what your requirements actually are so it's hard to say for sure but be aware of the possible legal implications of storing credit card details in each of the countries where the app is to be used. There are strict requirements around this.