# Why I get the same device ID with my ProximityDevice in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, nfc, credit-card

I'm trying to get some info from my credit cards, and I have the impression that the only thing I can get is the NfcAdapter ID.

I'm using this code :

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    ProximityDevice _proximityDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

    public MainPage()
    {
        _proximityDevice.DeviceArrived += DeviceArrived;
    }

    private void DeviceArrived(ProximityDevice proximityDevice)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Debug.WriteLine(proximityDevice.DeviceId));
    }
```

Even if I try another credit card, I always get the same info :

`\\?\SWD#Nfp#NfcAdapter#{fb3842cd-9e2a-4f83-8fcc-4b0761139ae9}`

I have 2 questions :

1- Why I get the same info everytime ?

2- Is there a way to get other infos in my credit cards ?

`UPDATE`

I have a **Nokia Lumia 930**

Comment: Could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314228/windows-8-phone-access-to-nfc-reader

Answer (score 0):

You get the same information each time because the `proximityDevice` represents the hardware inside your phone; it does not represent the card. It should actually be the same as `_proximityDevice`.

Comment: So how can I get the info from the credit card and not the hardware inside my phone ?

Comment: The link above from @Kulasangar explains why.